# Bug in search results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, search

I did a search for "windows 2000", and on [page 2](https://superuser.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=windows%202000) of the results, I see the following:

[image]

Notice the [last question](https://superuser.com/questions/614477/how-to-lock-windows-screen-on-startup/) in the screenshot just says 4 votes.  I should actually say 1 vote and 2 answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last result is an answer, not question and hence says 4 votes and no mention of answers

Comment: … as indicated by the "A:" prefix to the title rather than "Q:".